# Is config.xml is created after the domain creation or when admin server starts for the first time in Weblogic?

Tags: weblogic12c

I read this in the official documentation but I am confused about config.xml.

When you start a server instance in a domain for the first time, WebLogic Server creates the following subdirectories in the domain directory:

Files containing security information

logs directory for storing domain-level logs

For each server running in the domain, a directory for storing server logs and HTTP access logs

Answer (score 0):

The config.xml file is created during the domain creation.